# Call jquery modal popup from asp.net dropdownlist change

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a requirement to do some logic execution upon change of dropdownlist value. Before executing the logic i need to take user confirmation and then call service side method to complete the process. Not sure How to call server side method based on modal popup confirmation response from user. So if user confirms with Yes button on the modal popup server side code should be called otherwise do nothing.

Here is the code i have . Server side does not get called upon modal popup confirmation.

```
    function PopupDialog(title, text) {
        var div = $('<div>').html('<br>'+text).dialog({
        title: title,
        modal: true,
        height: 190,
        width: 320,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');

            },
            "No": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');

            }
         }
         });

         return true;
      };



     <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="grdTransactions" SkinID="gridviewskin"  
        AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="30" Width="100%" 
        OnRowDataBound="grdTransactions_RowDataBound"
        OnDataBound="grdTransactions_DataBound"  
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="grdTransactions_SelectedIndexChanged">

       .............

    <asp:TemplateField Visible="true" HeaderText="Status" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblStatus"  Visible="False" Text='<%# ShowStatus( Container.DataItem ) %>' />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTransactionList" AutoPostBack="True"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTransactionList_SelectedIndexChanged" onchange="return PopupDialog('Remittance Confirmation','Are you sure you want to update the status?.');"  runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            <br/>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>


   **Server Side Code --**
    protected void ddlTransactionList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, 
          EventArgs e)
    {
        //Your Code
        if (OnDataChanged != null)
            OnDataChanged(sender, e);
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a conflict between the javascript created by ASP.NET and the onchange event you are adding to the dropdown (onchange="return .... ") so it is ignoring the the call that posts back.

I would start by trying something like this on the front end:

```
// remove the autopostback & onchange from the ddl definition
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTransactionList" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>

function PopupDialog(title, text) {
    var div = $('<div>').html('<br>'+text).dialog({
    title: title,
    modal: true,
    height: 190,
    width: 320,
    buttons: {
        "Yes": function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            return true;
        },
        "No": function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});
```

};

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("<% ddlTransactionList.CLientID %>").change(function(){
        if(PopupDialog('Remittance Confirmation','Are you sure you want to update the status?.')){
            __doPostBack('ddlTransactionList')
        }
    });
});
```

In the code-behind:

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string parameter = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]; // parameter
    // Request["__EVENTTARGET"]; // ddlTransactionList
    // make your call to ddlTransactionList_SelectedIndexChanged() here
}
```

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: the only thing is this code is in user control and not on main page.

Comment: What issue is that causing in relation to the answer I posted?